# Make visual studio code detect python compatibility errors

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Is there anything that allows visual studio code to tell you if you are writing python code that is not compatible with both python 2 and 3 versions? I know that PyCharm has this feature but I'd prefer not to switch between IDEs depending on the language I'm coding in.

For example, `print "Hello world!"` should give me an error because its not compatible with python 3. `assert 3 / 2 == 1.5` should give me an error because it's not compatible with python 2.

Comment: The first one should already be caught in Python 3 mode, because it's a syntax error. You can catch a lot more things by [installing and configuring one or more linters](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting#_specific-linters). But I don't think any of the common linters or static analyzers will catch the invalid `assert`—they won't even catch `assert 3 == 2`.

Comment: I wonder how PyCharm does it then...

Answer (score 1):

If you set up [linting in the Python extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting) and then set up Pylint to run with `--py3k` turned on then you will get warnings about Python 2/3 compatibility.